# Retrieve naturalWidth of updated image src

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".photo").on('click', function(){
    this.src = this.src.replace(/thumb/g, 'original');
    alert(this.naturalWidth);
}
```

I am using jQuery in Rails4 to update the src attribute of an image. I am also using paperclip for image uploading.

The flow: when I click the image in the first time, it returns the thumb width(140px). However, the subsequent clicks return the natural width of the original image(1200px).

Is it possible to get the natural width of the original image in the first time?

Comment: Wait for the image to load..

Comment: You need to wait for the image to load. Hook to the `load` event of the `img` element. It most likely works for the first image because it is already cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wait for the image to be loaded. [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) handler will be invoked when image has finished `loading`

This event will fire every time `src` property of the `image` is changed.

Try this:

```js
$(".photo").on('click', function() {
      this.src = this.src.replace(/thumb/g, 'original');
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        alert(this.naturalWidth);
      }
      img.src = this.src;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What's the use of `img.src = this.src;`? I only need the naturalWidth value. With your code, I cannot get it in the first time.

Comment: `img.src = this.src;` will set the `src` property of the `new Image()` object and it will invoke `onload` event..Create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your example which is failing for above code

Comment: Too excited for getting the naturalWidth at first click, but how to use the value in outer function? I've tried `alert(img.naturalWidth);` in the on click function, but it returns 0 after the first click.

Comment: This isn't correct, since it'll wait until the *entire* image is loaded, and naturalWidth and naturalHeight are updated much sooner than that.  That means you'll keep using the old dimensions while the image loads (potentially showing a stretched image with a different aspect ratio), and only update it at the very end, when you almost always will want to update it right when it starts loading.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(".photo").on('click', function(){
          $("<img/>")  
                .attr("src", $(this).attr("src"))
                .load(function() { 
                    alert(this.width)
                    alert(this.height)
                });  

});
```

Comment: I was currently reviewing your post. "code only" answers are not a good idea unless they explain how the question is answered/ problem is solved within the code in the form of comments.

Comment: yes your correct and by the way this is my first anz in stackoverflow
future i'll comment for my code

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider reading [Help Center > Answering > How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve the quality of your future answers. ;)

Comment: Thanks you for the link